# Cannot connect to SMB shares when network location is "Domain Netowork" Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, server-message-block, cifs

PROBLEM:

Access to the shares work when the network is "Public Network" or "Private Network" but not when it is "Domain Network".

QUESTION:

What different things change with the Network Location type, aside from firewall settings?

BACKGROUND:

I have some strange proprietary machines that connect using SMBv1 using very old protocols. I have shares set up for them in a Windows 2008 R2 and it was working just fine. I had to change some security options to allow LM & NTLM authentication. When I first got it working the network was erroneously identified as "Public Network". At some point, a Windows update fixed this and now it is correctly identified as "Domain Network". The machines can no longer connect. I got it to work again by changing the Network Location to "Public" but it breaks on each reboot. I really need to know why the shares change with the network location but I can't seem to find any information about that.

NOTE:

I have tried turning the firewall off. All of the "Advanced Sharing Settings" are identical for all 3 network profiles. What else changes?

Comment: Which side of the connection is the one changing the network type? Are you changing the network type on the file server hosting the shares or on the client machine that is accessing the shares?

Comment: The server side changes on reboot. The client side is not Windows.